# Inserting very large insert to mysql, max_packet_size

Tags: mysql

We're trying to install the manatee software, and we're getting this error.

```
mysql -u manatee cgspu -p --max_allowed_packet=4096M < to-insert.sql
Warning: option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 4294967296 adjusted to 2147483648
Enter password: 
ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 1: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

Mysql is indeed setting max_allowed_packets, we check with `mysql --help`
which shows

```
max_allowed_packet                2147483648
```

Is there any way to circumvent this? I had to remove that single line from initial database fill in the makefile to even get it to install the software.

Now I'm left with a line outside of the database and no way to insert it.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

You might need to set `max_allowed_packet` **on the server**.

Try this:

```
(echo 'SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;' ; cat to-insert.sql) |
mysql -u manatee cgspu -p --max_allowed_packet=1073741824
```

and see if that fixes your issue.

Does `to-insert.sql` contain a single SQL statement greater than 2G?

Or does it contain a multi-line `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO example VALUES 
(1),(2),(3), ....
```

If so, rewrite these as individual `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO example VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO example VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO example VALUES (3);
```

If you created `to-insert.sql` using `mysqldump`, try re-exporting the records with:

```
mysqldump --skip-extended-insert ...
```

Comment: to-insert contains a single SQL statement. `du -h to-insert.sql 
4,8M    to-insert.sql`. The main crux of the problem is a 4,969,807 character insert to a `longtext` field.

Comment: The   insert wasn't created by us using mysqldump, it came packaged with the software we wish to use.

Comment: @EricR, Won't that 4,969,807 character insert get truncated to 4GB since LONGTEXT is limited to 4GB?

Comment: @MarcusAdams, I would imagine that it would. Unfortunately some idiotic dev decided it was a great idea to store whole bacterial genomes in a database in longtext, rather than on disc. I cannot for the life of me understand why.

Comment: I'm still not able to insert the record, so if it's simply not possible to insert the 5 million character record I guess we'll live without. I'm not sure what impact it would have on the software but it probably wouldn't be the end of the world.